# :first-child, :last-child not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a graphic element that I want to position on top of another element.
Because I do not want to create css selectors for those that have no re-use,
I have applied psuedo class. `:first-element` that is supposed to sit on top of the other is hidden by the other element.

Here is my [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/ULiFoyo/5/edit)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  top:25px;
  left: 25px; 
  background: red;
  z-index: 100;
}
.wrapper:last-child {
  position: relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: orange;
}
```

**Added**

Thanks for all your input.
Now I understand where I got this wrong (psuedo class to be applied to child element)

I've made up the sample to isolate my problem but
I am actually doing this for `<img>` elements where one `<img>` sits on top of the other `<img>`
and the html structure is

```
<div class="brand">
    <a href="#"><img src=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src=""/></a>
</div>
```

css is

```
.brand img:last-child {
    position: relative;
}
.brand img:first-child {  
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:15px;
}
```

They are not working like the simple div example. I guess that is because there is another anchor element that needs to be taken into account for.

Comment: you need to apply this to an actual child: 'wrapper div:first-child'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `.wrapper > div:first-child` and `.wrapper > div:last-child` instead.

```
.wrapper > div:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  top:25px;
  left: 25px; 
  background: red;
  z-index: 100;
}
.wrapper > div:last-child {
  position: relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: orange;
}
```

As per you edit:

You should do like this

```
.brand a:last-child img {
    position: relative;
}
.brand a:first-child img {  
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:15px;
}
```

Comment: He doesn't have to use `>` he was simply forgetting the `whitespace` in `.wrapper :first-child`

Comment: @Itay: You still have to decide between whitespace and `>`. It's one or the other. That's how combinators work.

Comment: @BoltClock I know that but this answer make it sound like the problem was he wasn't using `>` and not the fact that he was referring the container as if it was the child.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think @Itay pointed out the core problem of my approach.

Comment: @SeongLee Yes, but C-Link's solution is still a more correct way.

Comment: @C-Link Would you mind taking a look at the updated question?